# Marginalization in gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

If $\theta|\mu \sim N(\mu,\sigma_o^2)$ and $\mu \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ what is the marginalized $P(\theta)$.

$\theta$ and $\mu$ both are nx1 vectors

$P(\theta) = \int P(\theta|\mu)P(\mu)d\mu$

Is it $N(0,\sigma_o^2I+\sigma_1^2A)$?

where A is nxn matrix with all ones?

Comment: $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2$ have to be covariance matrices for their definitions to be sensical. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Is $\mu$ a scalar or a $n$-vector?  You say $n$-vector, but if that really is the case, what are the covariance matrices for $\theta$ and $\mu$?